# mercurial automatic push on every commit

Tags: mercurial, automation

Being very familiar with the subversion workflow and that fact that 99.9% of the time my computer is connected to the internet, I don't like doing 'hg ci' and 'hg push' separately.

I remember bzr had a 'checkout' command that would bind subsequent 'commit' commands to automatically commit directly to the server ('push').

Does mercurial have something similar to this?

PS: Writing a shell script or alias that runs 'hg ci $* && hg push' would be the last thing I'd do.

Comment: Why not a script? Doesn't a hook make the 0.1% of times you want to commit without a push much harder?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could add a [hook](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) to run push after a successful commit.

**EDIT:** I just tried it out and it seems to work fine.  I added the following to the `.hg/hgrc` file of the repository I wanted to activate automatic pushing for:

```
[hooks]
commit.autopush = hg push
```

**EDIT 2:** Also, you **don't** have to worry about something like this:

- You're in a repository that you **don't** want to automatically push.
- You use `hg -R ~/another-repo-that-autopushes commit` to commit in a different repo that **does** automatically push.
- Will the `hg push` hook end up pushing the changes in the current directory instead of the one you're committing in?

No, it won't.  According to the page I linked:

> An executable hook is always run with its current directory set to a repository's root directory.

It's an edge case, but Mercurial handles it correctly.

Comment: The problem with this hook is that mq commands that create temporary commits (qnew, qpush, etc.) will trigger a push. Using the post-commit hook might be a better idea.

Comment: @hwiechers: can you give an example of how to write a post-commit hook?

Comment: @max: Instead of using `commit.autopush = hg push` do `post-commit.autopush = hg push`. The post-commit hook runs after the commit command successfully completes. The commit hook runs whenever a changeset is created in the local repository. See http://linux.die.net/man/5/hgrc for details.