# Automatically backup work project git or hg on commit

Tags: git, mercurial, backup, project-management

When I commit some changes by git or mercurial, I would like to automatically backup (or do similar changes) in another place (backup directory for this project.)

Is it possible?

Comment: For mercurial, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235597/mercurial-automatic-push-on-every-commit

Comment: If you're willing to make the backup directory a repository as well, you can simply make it a remote repo and push to it from the post-commit hook.

Comment: Could you provide more details ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. In folder .hg I created myhook.sh file and I changed hgrc. 
I have done in this way:

```
.hg/hgrc: 
[hooks]
commit =/fullPathToMyHook/myhook.sh

myhook.sh:
hg pull /pathToMyBackUpProject
hg merge
hg update
hg push /pathToMyBackUpProject
```

Now, then I write

```
hg commit
```

it automatically:
commit my changes,
get last changes from my backup storage,
merge it,
update and push all changes to backup storage.